# simple probability with marbles - requery

Tags: probability, statistics

There is a post about how to calculate [probability with marbles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/403694/simple-probability-with-marbles).

I doubt the answer and i am asking for a more detailed explanation if possible.

Picking marbles without replacement and without caring about the order.

There are two groups of marbles in the bag. $n$ type A marbles and $k$ type B marbles.
I want to pick a mix of $m$ type A marbles and $j$ type B marbles.

If i read the answer correctly this is supposed to be calculated like so:

$$ \frac{1}{P} =  \binom{n}{m}  \binom{k}{j} $$

If that were correct the probability of picking 4 red marbles and 2 blue marbles from a bag of 4 red marbles and 12 blue marbles would be $ \frac{1}{P} =  \binom{4}{4}  \binom{12}{2} = \binom{12}{2}$

I either misunderstood the answer or the ammount of red marbles do not matter as long as i want to pick all of them.

What is actually correct and why?

---

Edit: The original post was correct - i just misread it. The answers here explain what i misread.

Comment: The answer is $p=\binom{n}{m}\binom{k}{j}\binom{n+k}{m+j}^{-1}$ and not $p=\binom{n}{m}^{-1}\binom{k}{j}^{-1}$ as you suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Picking $m+j$ marbles from a total of $n+k$ marbles can be done on $\binom{n+k}{m+j}$ ways.

However, if it is done under the restriction that $m$ are of type $A$ and $j$ of type $B$ then it can be done on $\binom{n}{m}\binom{k}{j}$ ways.

So the probability of that event is: $$\binom{n}{m}\binom{k}{j}\binom{n+k}{m+j}^{-1}$$

Answer (score 2):

In a simpler case, if you want to choose k items out of n items, the number of ways to do it is $\binom nk$, now if the $k$ is equal to $n$, i.e. when you want to take all the items, there is only one way to do it, you take it all, and that'd be $\binom nn =1$.

Similarly, here since you want all 4 red ones, you only have one way to do it, and then you want to choose the 2 blue, which can be out of the 12.

And to make it to a probability, you divide it by the total number of ways to choose 6 out of 16.